# when i run the spring-hadoop-sample in github and find my yarn application start with fail status

Tags: java, spring-boot, hadoop, sample

I'm very new to Hadoop, now I am running Pseudo-Distributed model at one machine, and I want to run the yarn sample in GitHub.https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/tree/master/boot/yarn-boot-simple.
but when I run the jar according to the guidance I found my yarn application was failed in the application list.

I had run the start-all.sh, and it seems everything is ok, the nodes are running when I use jps -l command

```
[root@server25 container_1550477585755_0003_02_000001]# jps|grep Node
24731 SecondaryNameNode
25286 NodeManager
24018 NameNode
24275 DataNode
```

when I run the jar, here is the log:

```
[root@server25 jar_repo]# java -jar yarn-boot-simple-client-0.1.0.jar 

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.3.RELEASE)

[2019-02-18 17:40:49.706] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- ClientApplication: Starting ClientApplication on server25 with PID 11970 (/opt/HADOOP/jar_repo/yarn-boot-simple-client-0.1.0.jar started by root in /opt/HADOOP/jar_repo)
[2019-02-18 17:40:49.805] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2ca0cbe4: startup date [Mon Feb 18 17:40:49 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
[2019-02-18 17:40:53.187] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- ConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor: No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
[2019-02-18 17:40:53.195] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- ConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor: No bean named 'taskExecutor' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default SyncTaskExecutor will be created.
[2019-02-18 17:40:53.210] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[2019-02-18 17:40:53.891] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- ThreadPoolTaskExecutor: Initializing ExecutorService  'metricsExecutor'
[2019-02-18 17:40:56.060] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- SpringYarnConfiguration: Enabling CLIENT for Yarn
[2019-02-18 17:40:56.072] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- SpringYarnConfiguration: We couldn't figure out if we could use existing configuration
[2019-02-18 17:40:56.072] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- SpringYarnConfiguration: Building configuration for bean 'yarnConfiguration'
[2019-02-18 17:40:56.284] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- SpringYarnConfigBuilder: Existing yarnConfiguration: null
[2019-02-18 17:40:57.117] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- ConfigurationFactoryBean: Overwriting fsUri=[file:///] with fsUri=[hdfs://localhost:8020]
[2019-02-18 17:40:57.118] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- ConfigurationFactoryBean: Overwriting rmAddress=[0.0.0.0:8032] with rmAddress=[localhost:8032]
[2019-02-18 17:40:58.083] boot - 11970  WARN [main] --- NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[2019-02-18 17:40:58.365] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- ConfigurationFactoryBean: Executing with tokens:
[2019-02-18 17:40:58.399] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- SpringYarnConfigBuilder: Setting configuration for SpringYarnConfigs:  fs.defaultFS=hdfs://localhost:8020 yarn.resourcemanager.address=localhost:8032 Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml
[2019-02-18 17:40:58.409] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- EnvironmentFactoryBean: Adding CLASSPATH=./*
[2019-02-18 17:40:59.181] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- ThreadPoolTaskScheduler: Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
[2019-02-18 17:40:59.191] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
[2019-02-18 17:40:59.203] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Starting beans in phase 0
[2019-02-18 17:40:59.612] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- ClientApplication: Started ClientApplication in 11.105 seconds (JVM running for 12.658)
[2019-02-18 17:40:59.818] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- AbstractYarnClient: submitApplication, got applicationId=[application_1550477585755_0004]
[2019-02-18 17:40:59.818] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- AbstractResourceLocalizer: Setting stagingId=application_1550477585755_0004
[2019-02-18 17:40:59.818] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- AbstractResourceLocalizer: Marking distributed state false
[2019-02-18 17:40:59.819] boot - 11970  INFO [main] --- AbstractResourceLocalizer: About to distribute localized files
[2019-02-18 17:41:03.150] boot - 11970  INFO [Thread-2] --- AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2ca0cbe4: startup date [Mon Feb 18 17:40:49 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
[2019-02-18 17:41:03.163] boot - 11970  INFO [Thread-2] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Stopping beans in phase 0
[2019-02-18 17:41:03.166] boot - 11970  INFO [Thread-2] --- ThreadPoolTaskScheduler: Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
[2019-02-18 17:41:03.171] boot - 11970  INFO [Thread-2] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
[2019-02-18 17:41:03.172] boot - 11970  INFO [Thread-2] --- ThreadPoolTaskExecutor: Shutting down ExecutorService 'metricsExecutor'
```

and the `/opt/HADOOP/hadoop-2.9.2/logs/userlogs/application_1550477585755_0004/container_1550477585755_0004_02_000001/Appmaster.stdout` log below:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.3.RELEASE)

[2019-02-18 17:41:11.945] boot - 12386  INFO [main] --- AppmasterApplication: Starting AppmasterApplication on server25 with PID 12386 (/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1550477585755_0004/filecache/10/yarn-boot-simple-appmaster-0.1.0.jar started by root in /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1550477585755_0004/container_1550477585755_0004_02_000001)
[2019-02-18 17:41:12.038] boot - 12386  INFO [main] --- AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2ca0cbe4: startup date [Mon Feb 18 17:41:12 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
[2019-02-18 17:41:14.261] boot - 12386  INFO [Thread-2] --- AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2ca0cbe4: startup date [Mon Feb 18 17:41:12 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
[2019-02-18 17:41:14.266] boot - 12386  WARN [Thread-2] --- AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2ca0cbe4: startup date [Mon Feb 18 17:41:12 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:804)
[2019-02-18 17:41:14.273] boot - 12386  WARN [Thread-2] --- AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2ca0cbe4: startup date [Mon Feb 18 17:41:12 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:804)
```

the only thing I can make sure is the jar started and then shut down by itself, does anyone can help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: I found when I switch jdk8 to jdk7 and rerun the sample, then the yarn application state change to RUNNING and the FinalStatus change to UNDEFINED, which both were FAILED before. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bother you if you are trying to help me to solve this issue, I figure it out when I switch my JDK version from jdk8 to jdk7 according to the java versions guide here https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopJavaVersions.Finaly the state and the FinalStatus are FINISHED and SUCCEEDED. thanks to the friends who are trying to help me.

Comment: But when I switch my jdk version from 7 to 8 and it still works right, I was confused, I just don't understand what's the difference between this two environment.the first machine is company's test server, and the second machine is my vitual machine,maybe the centos' version?